# Qt Qgis mouse event on QgsMapCanvasItem

Tags: qgis, qt

I'm trying to intercept the mouse event on a QgsMapCanvasItem.
I create a new class that extends the QgsMapCanvasItem, and override the mouseReleaseEvent (i put a qDebug inside).
As long as I tried a lot of time but the event is never fired.
There is something I'm missing?

I'm using Qt Designer and the compiled source of Qgis 2.99.

```
class PlatformMarker : public QgsMapCanvasItem
{
    ...
    private:
        virtual void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
};
```

In cpp:

```
void PlatformMarker::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "Custom item clicked.";
    QgsMapCanvasItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: if you want help with debugging code your are expected to show your efforts so please include your which produces the error